# PostgreSQL High Performance Setup

Tags: linux, performance, postgresql, partition

I am setting up a server with the following specs:
* Qty 4 Processors (AMD Opterons with 12 cores each)
* 32 GB Memory
* Qty 8 HDD (15K SAS Dual Port)
* CentOS 5.5
* JBoss
* PostgreSQL

It is likely that at a later point I will separate the application from the database but for now they are going to be on the same machine.  I have read that PostgreSQL performance benefits from:
* RAID 10
* Separate OS partition
* Separate xlog partition
* Separate pgdata partition

Since my single RAID 10 volume seems to have a total of 559808 MB available, this is the current partition plan:
* 337856 MB for OS
* 102400 MB for pgdata
* 51200 MB for xlog
* 68352 MB for swap

Here are some questions:
* How does my partition plan look?
* When installing CentOS, when I get to the disk setup step I need to define mount points - what should I enter for the pgdata partition? (ex. ref [this example setup mount points /pgdata1](http://nycdpug.x10hosting.com/cr.html) )
* What should I enter as the mount point for the xlog partition?
* For filesystem type, avoidance of corruption is more important than perfect performance so the plan is to use 'noatime' but leave 'data=ordered' for the partition mount options - what do you think?
* Any other considerations?

Note: It is likely that the total size of all databases in the pgdata partition will not grow beyond 20 GB in the next few years.